# Where are the tinfoil hats?

Tags: discussion, area-51

If we're supposed to have an *Xfilesy kooky conspiracy nut* meets *Plan 9 from Outer Space* theme to area 51, then I want cooler worthless shiny trinkets:

1. I don't want to be a [Pioneer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/205/pioneer), I want to be a *Space Cadet*,
2. I don't want a [Radical badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/202/radical), I want a *Tinfoil Hat*, and
3. I don't want to become a [Founder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/204/founder), I want to have *Made First Contact*.

What other shiny trinkets should we get?

Comment: Regarding the tag: R'Amen!

Answer (score 7):

First vote to delete a question: Government Cover-up
First edit: Reality Warper
First flagged post: Informant

Comment: Nice.  How about first edit giving *Interpolator*?

Comment: @Charles: if it's some quote, I don't get it :-/

Comment: An interpolator is someone who changes existing texts, with the connotation that this is done in an underhand manner, or involves falsification.